# JavaScript: Parsing a JSON object with multiple levels

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a JSON file with the following format:

```
{
  "Afghanistan": [
    {
      "date": "2020-1-22",
      "confirmed": 0,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-23",
      "confirmed": 0,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    ...
  ],
  "Albania": [
    {
      "date": "2020-1-22",
      "confirmed": 0,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-1-23",
      "confirmed": 0,
      "deaths": 0,
      "recovered": 0
    },
    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

My goal is to extract data in a way so as to get the date, confirmed, deaths and recovered of each country. The problem I am having is finding a way to do this for all countries as opposed to just one.

For instance, if I write the line `data.Afghanistan[0].confirmed; //data is a variable i stored the JSON object in`, to get info for Afghanistan, I would need to write the same line for Albania as well and for all other countries separately.

I know there a way I can do this for all counties in a more efficient way but I can't seem to find it. Can someone please help me out? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How do you want to access the data or in fact how do you want to use it?

Comment: Do you want like a consolidated total of `confirmed`, `deaths`, `recovered` for all countries for a given `date`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.keys()`. For example, `Object.keys(yourJSONObject)` will return an array of your keys, i.e. `["Afghanistan", "Albania"]`. You can use this to iterate over each key/value in your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work:

```js
const countries = Object.keys(data);
const confirmedDeathsByCountry = countries.map(country => data[country][0].confirmed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the arrays inside each country in your JSON file like so:

```
for (var key in data) { 
    //key is the country ie. "Afghanistan"
    var records = data[key]; //array of records
    for (var index in records) {
        var record = records[index]; //object with the properties
        var date = record.date;
        var confirmed = record.confirmed;
        var deaths = record.deaths;
        var recovered = record.recovered;
    }
}
```